# Strava authorization working on local host but not when published to azure

Tags: asp.net, azure, asp.net-core, strava

The following code authorizes my strava account in my web app:

```
function Authorize() {
document.location.href = "https://www.strava.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=xxxxx&redirect_uri=https://localhost:44389/home/strava&response_type=code&scope=activity:read_all"

    }

    const codeExchangeLink = `https://www.strava.com/api/v3/oauth/token`
    function codeExchange() {


        fetch(codeExchangeLink, {
            method: 'post',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },

            body: JSON.stringify({
                client_id: '@ViewBag.cId',
                client_secret: '@ViewBag.cSec',
                code: '@ViewBag.code',
                //need to do this to get a new refresh token that 'reads all' and issues a new Access Token - refer to comments below
                grant_type: 'authorization_code'

            })
        })
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(res => getActivities(res))

    }
```

However, when I publish to azure and change the document.location.href code and redirect address (as below) to match my published app it fails with a 'bad request' error.

```
document.location.href  = "https://www.strava.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=xxxxx&redirect_uri=https://xxxx.azurewebsites.net/home/strava&response_type=code&scope=activity:read_all"
```

**Error is included below:**

> {"message":"Bad Request","errors":[{"resource":"Application","field":"redirect_uri","code":"invalid"}]}

Any help greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

This was totally my error (embarrassingly). The issue was in my Strava Api App Settings, my call back uri was set to the default 'developers.strava.com'. All I had to do was change it to match my Published Web App uri 'xxxx.azurewebsites.net/home/strava' and it now works.